A tag for altered states of consciosness?
We've had a few questions about hypnosis, drug induced hallucinations, alcohol intoxication, and so on.

Do we need a tag for altered states of consciousness?
If so, what should it be?

Examples:

Can a person be hypnotized to act drunk?
What is the difference between hypnosis and meditation?
Sensory Immersion Research?


We need a tag for:

Drugs
Mind-altering substances
Hallucinations

etc. al
